Xunit Serialize/Deserialize Custom Type
I'm trying to serialize / deserialize a unique type as part of an xunit c# test.
The type is
List<GraphicTestCase<TPage>> _testCases = new();

GraphicTestCase looks like the following:

public interface IGraphicTestCase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IWebElement Execute();
}

public abstract class GraphicTestBase<TPage,TReturn> where TPage : BasePage
{
    private readonly Func<TPage> _pageFactory;
    public GraphicTestBase(Func<TPage> pageFactory)
    {
        _pageFactory = pageFactory;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Func<TPage, TReturn> Action { get; set; }

    public TReturn Execute()
    {
        TPage page = _pageFactory();
        return Action(page);
    }
}

public class GraphicTestCase<TPage> : GraphicTestBase<TPage, IWebElement> , IGraphicTestCase where TPage : BasePage
{
    public GraphicTestCase(Func<TPage> pageFactory) : base(pageFactory)
    {
    }
}

Here is my current serialization/deserialization

    public void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                IgnoreSerializableInterface = false,
                IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false,
            },
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_testCases, settings);

        // Add serialized data to the serialization info
        info.AddValue("TestCases", json);
    }

    public void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        string json = info.GetValue<string>("TestCases");
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                IgnoreSerializableInterface = false,
                IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false
            },
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        var cases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GraphicTestCase<TPage>>>(json, settings);
        _testCases.Clear();

        foreach (var testCase in cases)
        {
            _testCases.Add(testCase);
        }   
    }
}

Attempting to serialize / deserialize these values prevents my tests from being discovered in the test explorer, thus troubleshooting is quite hard.

They are not discovered because there are no tests here. If you want what I think you want, then you will probably want a [Theory] with [ClassData(typeof(YourTestCases))]

there are 500 tests in the project, when xunit has a serialization issue, all tests are not discoverable :(

Tbh I've never before seen or heard of anyone trying to serialize/deserialize tests (not only test data). Either I am missing something or you're doing it wrong. Again: For xUnit Tests to be discovered you need (at least) a class that contains (at least) a method that is annotated with either [Fact] or [Theory]. Theory tests are typically parameterized and can be fed through different data sources. For test data to be stored in json files, I'd use TheoryData<T>
